# Git log --branches with multiple branches using glob patterns

Tags: git, git-extensions

I can't get `git log --branches` to do what I want. I want to output, in a single graph, commits matching these glob patterns:

- `users/userA/*`
- `fix/*`
- `master`

I tried these approaches which don't work (they display commits from the current branch):

- `git log --branches="users/bertgp/* /users/sessid/* master"`
- `git log --branches="users/bertgp/*|/users/sessid/*|master"` (regex-like syntax)

Is this possible? It seems that glob patterns don't have an `or` syntax.

#### Why I want to do this

I am using [Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) as my visual git client and its [branch filter box appends its content to a (single) `--branches=` option](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1285) for its `git log` command.

I opened a [Git Extensions feature request](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3546) to support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in Git Extensions 2.49 (not check earlier versions). Though it is cumbersome...

Actually text from branch filter inserted into git command line as-is (or prefixed by `--branches=`) without escaping or somethig similar. Which means that you can add arbitrary git options.

Here is next things you should know:

1. if branch filter contains globing symbols, then GitExt prefixed it with `--branches=`
2. git does not accept more than one branch for log, so you should use `--branches` for every branch
3. for remote branches should be used `--remotes`
4. if used branch without globing, then git automatically add `/*` to end of branch, so you can't use `--branches=master`, instead you should use `--branches=maste[r]` with fake globing

Some examples:

1. `users/berniegp/* --branches=maste[r]`

Should do what you asking for. It will be converted by GitExt to `--branches=users/berniegp/* --branches=maste[r]`

2. `users/berniegp/* --branches=maste[r] --remotes=origin/users/berniegp/*`

Also show remote tracking branches (origin/users/berniegp/*)

3. `--reflog`

Show also commits which references from reflog. May be useful for find 'lost' commits?

4. `--bisect`

Should (I don't try it actually) show range of commits where problem was introduced (between good and bad)

5. `--reverse`

Show commits in reverse order.

And other options of `git log` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Answer (score 4):

You can repeat the `--branches` option multiple times:

```
git log --branches="users/bertgp/*" --branches="/users/sessid/*"
```

In bash, it can be compressed, taking advantage of brace expansion, to

```
git log --branches={"users/bertgp/*","/users/sessid/*"}
```

However, most probably, neither of these answers to your original question will work with Git Extensions.

Comment: This works in the command line, but it doesn't fit my use-case (see my edit). I'll accept this answer if no other one comes up.